# How can I use Google Smart Lock for Passwords on Android in a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I want to use [Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/) in my Cordova app. How can I do that? Do I need to write a Cordova plugin?

Answer (score -1):

Bit late, but might be useful for others looking for the same. Basically, you can make use of [Google's Credentials API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/CredentialsApi). More info about how to use it can be found here - https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/